# Custom suggestions in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to make the keyboard custom suggestions? I have been looking and I only find a way to deactivate the suggestions but not to personalize them.

I'm trying to create a completed auto for a user TextField. The username is an email that can have two possible endings [@nauta.con.cu, @nauta.co.cu]. I have already managed to implement a completed auto for the first possible termination, and I want to show the second possible termination as a suggestion on the keyboard.